# Doctrine OneToOne remove entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, one-to-one

When I remove entity, relations OneToOne has not been removed. Gallery has been removed successfully from database, but largeImage, mediumImage and smallImage not.

What I do wrong?

Delete action in controller:

```
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $offer = $em->getRepository('ToCmsBundle:Offer')->find($id);

    if($offer) {

        if(!$offer->getGallery()->isEmpty()) {
            foreach($offer->getGallery() as $key => $image) {
                $image->setOffer(null);
                $offer->removeGallery($image);
                //$em->remove($image);
                //$em->flush();
                echo $image->getPath() . '<br/>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'gallery is empty';
        }

        $offer->setLargeImage(null);
        $offer->setMediumImage(null);
        $offer->setSmallImage(null);

        $em->remove($offer);

        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('to_offer_list'));
}
```

My owner class:

```
/**
 * Offer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="to_offer")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="To\CmsBundle\Repository\OfferRepository")
 */
class Offer {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="offer", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $gallery;

    /**
     * @var Image
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    public $largeImage;

    /**
     * @var Image
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    public $mediumImage;

    /**
     * @var Image
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    public $smallImage;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="to_articles_categories")
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @var User
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->gallery = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** other stuff */
}
```

Image class:

```
/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="to_images")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="To\CmsBundle\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hashName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $hashName;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="originalImage", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $originalImage;

    /**
     * @var Offer
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Offer", inversedBy="gallery")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $offer;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="x", type="integer")
     */
    protected $x = 0;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="y", type="integer")
     */
    protected $y = 0;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="w", type="integer")
     */
    protected $w = 0;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="h", type="integer")
     */
    protected $h = 0;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="defaultImage", type="boolean")
     */
    private $default = 0;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
        $this->default = 0;
        $this->x = 0;
        $this->y = 0;
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        $this->position = $this->position ?: 0;
        $this->default = $this->default ?: 0;
        $this->x = $this->x ?: 0;
        $this->y = $this->y ?: 0;

        /*if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $this->name = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->originName = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();
            $this->extension = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();

            $this->path = $this->name.'.'.$this->extension;
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {

        echo $this->getRootPath().$this->originalImage; echo '<br/>';
        echo $this->getRootPath().$this->thumbnail; echo '<br/>';
        echo $this->getRootPath().$this->path; echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/><br/>';

        if(file_exists($this->getRootPath().$this->originalImage))
            unlink($this->getRootPath().$this->originalImage);
        if(file_exists($this->getRootPath().$this->thumbnail))
            unlink($this->getRootPath().$this->thumbnail);
        if(file_exists($this->getRootPath().$this->path))
            unlink($this->getRootPath().$this->path);
    }
    /** other stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entities are referencing each other so you should try remove these :

```
$offer->setLargeImage(null);
$offer->setMediumImage(null);
$offer->setSmallImage(null);
```

and call `flush()` once before `$em->remove($offer);` and once after.

```
foreach ($offer->getGallery() as $image) {
    $offer->removeGallery($image);
}
$em->flush();

$em->remove($offer);
$em->flush();
```

This will only work as is if all the images are "privately owned", meaning that they are not referenced multiple times in this entity or in another entity.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! But I have one question. Why i must use flush two times?

Comment: You cannot remove both in one go because they reference each other. There are foreign keys on both sides. You have to set the foreign keys on one side to NULL first, then you can delete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $offer->setLargeImage(null);
    $offer->setMediumImage(null);
    $offer->setSmallImage(null);
```

Your "$offer" doesn't have the images anymore when you're deleting it.

**UPDATE**

When you are doing your 'find()' you don't have the image object, but a proxy because of the lazy loading. If you need the offer with image objects, create a query with leftJoin on the images to get the offer AND images. And then, I think that you'll not have problems.

(look at the end of this tutorial to have an example of a leftjoin on objects : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#gerer-les-roles-via-la-base-de-donnees)

Comment: Yes, but if I commented this line, I have SQL error like this:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cms-symfony`.`to_images`, CONSTRAINT `FK_C6CDB2F753C674EE` FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `to_offer` (`id`))

From http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal we can learn how to remove entity, but this doesn't work for me.